# Visual Studio Graphics Debugger throws read access violation exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, directx-11

I'm writing a simple renderer using the d3d11 library in Visual Studio 2019 and it builds and runs fine. However when I try running the Graphics Debugger it immediately throws a read access violation for address 0x0000000000000000 ( which is clearly incorrect ).

The exception is thrown from the DXCaptureReplay dll on the line

```
DeviceContext.PSSetShader(InShaderToBind.Shader.PS, NULL, 1);
```

Where InShaderToBind.Shader.PS is a pointer to ID3D11PixelShader

It got the most weird when I out of a lack of ideas tried

```
int X = 0;
ID3D11ClassInstance* FakedClassInstance = reinterpret_cast<ID3D11ClassInstance*>(&X);

DeviceContext.PSSetShader(InShaderToBind.Shader.PS, &FakedClassInstance, 1);
```

As this will make the exception not throw until I try to capture a frame ( Which I guess makes sense as that pointer will only be valid for the scope where X is still valid )

The MSDN documentation states that NULL should be a perfectly valid argument to pass to PSSetShader ( as noted here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-pssetshader )

Any ideas for what might be going wrong?

( If I comment out PSSetShader the exception is not thrown and I can take captures )

Comment: Somewhere you've got a null pointer. Fortunately Visual Studio has an amazing debugging utility. Check out the call stack (Usually found in the bottom right corner) to see if it offers any hints on what got nulled and when. If it's always null, go, looking for where it should have been set and find out why it wasn't. If it's the `NULL` in the call, then I guess your shader does use an instance and you'll have to track it down.

Comment: I've been hunting for nullptrs for quite some time in regards to this but so far no luck. Will keep on looking though! How would I know exactly if my shader is using an instance?

Comment: Dunno. I just read the documentation and it said that the argument can only be `NULL` if the shader doesn't need an instance. How to find out if it needs one is unfortunately out of my wheelhouse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable the Direct3D Debug Device, you would see in your debug output window:

```
D3D11 CORRUPTION: ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShader: Second parameter (ppClassInstances) corrupt or unexpectedly NULL. [ MISCELLANEOUS CORRUPTION #14: CORRUPTED_PARAMETER2]
```

`NULL` (or better yet `nullptr`) is fine for `ppClassInstances` **only** if NumClassInstances is 0. Try:

```
DeviceContext.PSSetShader(InShaderToBind.Shader.PS, NULL, 0);
```

> Generally you should make sure your program runs without emitting ERROR or CORRUPTION messages from the debug layer before attempting to use PIX or the VSGS tool.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps) and [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/).